# Raise Event on When a different event raised - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, c#-4.0

I have made my own Button User control in a WPF application.

In this, I'm trying to raise a event attached with multiple event handlers on another event.

I have multiple event handlers attached with "MouseUp" Event for View and business logic (MVVM). I just want to fire all the handlers attached with "MouseUp" event On "KeyUp" with "Enter" and "SpaceBar"

Here is the sample code which I used to raise "MouseUp" event on "KeyUp" if the key is enter or space

```
 void Button_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.Enter)
      {
          RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
          {
              RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent,
              Source = this,
          });
       }                
  }
```

Not sure.  I may be wrong.  But it worked for me. However, not in all case.

In some of the cases, the event not raising as expected.

In my further investigation, Im seeing the key up event get triggered. But the none of the event handlers in "MouseUp" event raised in some objects.

Is there any elegant way to achieve my need.

Comment: Instead of trying to raise one event from inside another, unrelated event, extract the handling logic to a method and call it from both handlers

Comment: This sounds like a case of [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), asking about your attempted solution instead of the actual problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 4):

This breaks the expected pattern for anyone reading the code - why would the `mouseup` event need to be fired when the key is released? If it's just to avoid code duplication, you should have a separate method which both the `mouseup` and the `keyup` call.

As per the comments, if you have multiple event handlers attached, you will need to attach all of them to both events. Alternatively, you could create a meta-event-handler that calls all the others as methods, then just attach that one to each event.

Comment: Yes.  I did that to avoid code duplication.  Also, I have multiple event handlers attached with "MouseUp" Event for View and business logic (MVVM).  I just want to fire all the handlers attached with "MouseUP" On "KeyUp" with "Enter" and "SpaceBar"

Comment: Is there any other elegant way to do this.  Pls suggest me.  Tks. .

Comment: Attach all of those handlers to each event if you want all of those events to perform the same action.

Answer (score 1):

Just create function and work with events separately, adding reference to this function as events handler.